# How did 黑鍋 "black wok" semantically shift to mean "blame for a crime"?

Tags: etymology, idioms

https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/38716 spurred this question. [黑鍋 - Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%BB%91%E9%8D%8B#Chinese)

> 1. ([literally](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#literally)) [black](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/black) [wok](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wok)
> 2. ([figuratively](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#figurative)) [blame](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blame) for a [crime](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crime)

How did "black wok" semantically shift to mean definition 2 above? In 2020, Chinese cooking require [woks that are usually black](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8RRYPRqPWRE), so I can't imagine how it appertains to 'blame for a crime'?

[image]

As a verb, [背 'carry on the back' or 'bear'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%83%8C#Pronunciation_2). [Source for picture below](https://www.scmp.com/magazines/post-magazine/travel/article/2153115/why-taipeis-only-three-michelin-star-restaurant). [背黑鍋 - Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%83%8C%E9%BB%91%E9%8D%8B#Chinese)

> 1. ([idiomatic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#idiomatic)) to [take](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take) the [blame](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blame) (for someone else); to be a [scapegoat](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scapegoat)

[image]

Comment: Not sure it's the official version, so it appears here as a comment. Anyway the story goes that a thief when looking for something to steal in the kitchen hid behind a big 锅 when the house owner came unexpectedly. While making his escape he carried the 锅 on his back. The house owner saw this and told his neighbors that a thief stole his 锅 Later he realized that the thief only took the container of the 锅 which was still in the kitchen. So the thief was falsely blamed for stealing the 锅 with which he was "seen" carried on his back when making his escape. So, 背黑锅 became being blamed wrongly.

Comment: @WayneCheah interesting, it might be worth to move this comment to an answer

Comment: @blackgreen. Thanks for the comment on my comment  It's OK. Perhaps someday, someone somewhere might somehow find a dusty forgotten volume in a library in rural China containing the official version which may contradict my folk version and I may then have to, with tail between my legs, move it back to comment again. :)

Answer (score 1):

The Cantonese equivalent of 背黑鍋 is [替人孭鑊](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%AD%AD%E9%91%8A#Chinese)

鑊 is a slang for 'incident' e.g. 大鑊 (big wok = big incident). 孭鑊 (to carry the wok) means 'to take the responsibility/ blame (for an incident or mistake)' . "替人孭鑊" = "take blame for someone else" = "背黑鍋" in  Mandarin

Answer (score 0):

This meaning comes from a scene: two men went travel, one man want to eat rice on the road, but let the another one to carry the dirty wok which can cook rice.

Answer (score 0):

黑锅 is from 黑过, 过 means 过错, mistakes, it is similar to 王八蛋 which is from 忘八端.