# How does the hook in 甩 negative 用's meaning?

Tags: etymology, glyph-origin

I read [甩 - Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%94%A9#Etymology), and screenshot [Yellowbridge](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?zi=%E7%94%A9). 甩 appears the antonym of 用, and the hook (that I marked with the green arrow) appears the only difference between their logograms.

1. What's the correct term for this "hook"?
2. Please see the title.

> The [Cantonese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantonese) reading is probably unrelated, though it may reflect a descendant of the archaic pronunciation **rut* and hence be cognate with Mandarin. Either way, it is evidently from the same source as [Min Nan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_Min) *[甪](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%94%AA#Min_Nan)* (lut, “to come off, to slip loose”), [Zhuang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhuang_languages) *[lot](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lot#Zhuang)* (“to come loose and drop off (due to loose tying)”), and [Vietnamese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietnamese_language) *[lột](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/l%E1%BB%99t#Vietnamese)* (“to peel, to strip off”).

[image]

https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/38716 spurred this question.

Answer (score 2):

> What's the correct term for this "hook"?

“乚” is named “cjk stroke swag” (u+31df), as used in “己”, the third stroke.

https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U31C0.pdf

in chinese, it’s described as “豎曲鉤”, by the 教育部 異體字字典.

< https://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/variants/rbt/word_attribute.rbt?quote_code=QTAyNjI4>

> The Cantonese reading is probably unrelated

such claiming is wrong. it’s a cantonese character (粵字)

in 廣東通志 卷五十一, page 30 mentioned:

> 物之脫者曰**甩**・倫粒切・此粤字之隨俗撰出者也

https://archive.org/details/06041865.cn/page/n29/mode/1up

have fun :)

Comment: Thanks. Just checking if you answered question 2 in my post pls?